# Propagate value of variable to outside of the loop

Tags: bash, variables, loops

```
dpkg --list |grep linux-image |grep "ii  " | while read line
do
  arr=(${line})
  let i=i+1
  _constr+="${arr[2]} "
done
echo $i
echo ${_constr}
```

The echo statements outside of the loop do not display the expected variables.

How should I make the contents of the variable propagate outside the loop?

Comment: Keep in mind that the `while` loop runs in a separate process, this is the reason you don't see the changed variables.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The problem is the pipe, not the loop. Try it this way

```
let i=0
arr=()
_constr=

while read -r line ; do
    arr=("${line}")
    let i=i+1
    _constr+="${arr[2]} "
done < <(dpkg --list | grep linux-image | grep 'ii  ')

echo "$i"
echo "${_constr}"
```

Pipes are executed in a subshell, as noted by Blagovest in his comment. Using [process substitution instead](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) (this is the `< <(commands)` syntax) keeps everything in the same process, so changes to global variables are possible.

Incidentally, your pipeline could be improved as well

```
dpkg --list | grep '^ii.*linux-image'
```

One less invocation of `grep` to worry about.

Comment: In bash 3.x, the last line of loop should be like `done <<<\`commands\``

Comment: @Ida: What would be the advantage of doing that? Doing that would fail: the subshell would execute and return each result on its own line, which would then be smashed into a single string and fed to `read` at once, which would read until the first embedded newline, loop once and then `while`, having no more input to process, would terminate. This is not what you want. Only the first package version from the query would be in `_constr` afterward. The `<()` construct is understood by bash 3.x.

Comment: +1 + done[space]<[space]<(command)
                                            ^ no space above

Comment: For users reading that. Yes pipe is the origin of the issue, thank you @sorpigal, but when can keep the pipe with `{}` as @gilles-so-stop-being-evil said there https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9994/372108  with `cat junk | {  while read var ; do x=55 ; done  echo x=$x }`. It works for me.

Comment: @phili_b: that may work in some shells, but it doesn't work in all shells  (and not in `bash`). You should avoid relying on it.

Comment: It does work on my ubuntu 20 bash, I finalized a script this afternoon with that. Monday I'll paste its version.

Comment: `bash --version` : 
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: `seq 4 |{ while read id; do echo "hello: $id"; echo "--"; byeid=$id; done; echo "bye $byeid";}` works with this bash. Be careful at the space before the `while` else we get the error "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'".

Comment: If that's what you mean then that's different. You are still creating a subshell and variables still do not survive outside it, but they exist up to the end of your subshell--which now includes one statement outside the loop. Curly braces are not special here, they just make a larger [compound command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/chap2.html#tag_001_010_002)

Comment: Observe: `printf '%s\n' mike robert joe | ( while read i; do printf 'hello %s\n' "$i"; last=$i; done; printf 'goodbye %s\n' "$last" )` using a regular subshell-bonus points, whitespace around the parens are not required.

Comment: When I found this page and this one of unix stackexchange, It was for concatenate all codes found, by regex, inside each pdf and rename each pdf filename with those codes found, but I can concatenate only when I have a new file. So when I had 45 files, the 45th was not changed, ie your $last or my $byeid. Until I applied the answer of @gilles-so-stop-being-evil, but understanding that the cause was the pipe  like you explained. :)

Comment: And I prefere to have my `find` at the left-hand-side, ie before the pipe, and not at the right-hand-side after `< <`.

Comment: My anwser for concatenate all codes found, by regex, inside each pdf and rename each pdf filename with those codes found. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72324790/10489562

Answer (score 3):

This somewhat by-passes your question (and it's a good question), but you can achieve the same results using simply:

```
 _constr=($(dpkg --list | awk '/^ii.*linux-image/{print $2}'))
```

The `($(cmd))` construct initialises a bash array using the output of the command within.

```
[me@home]$ echo ${_constr[*]}
linux-image-2.6.35-22-generic linux-image-2.6.35-28-generic linux-image-generic
[me@home]$ echo ${_constr[2]}
linux-image-generic
```

and you can get the number of elements using `${#_constr[*]}`.

```
[me@home]$ echo ${#_constr[*]}
3
```

Comment: This is really the right way to do it. I didn't have a Debian box to test with or I'd have suggested the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can move the echo statements inside the subshell:

```
dpkg --list |grep linux-image |grep "ii  " | (
  let i=0
  declare -a arr

  while read line
  do
    arr=(${line})
    let i=i+1
    _constr+="${arr[2]} "
  done
  echo $i
  echo ${_constr}
)
```

Note the insertion of the parenthesis to explicitly define where the subshell begins and ends.