# how to control the value at the loop's end

Tags: bash, ubuntu-12.04

I have gone through various sources but could not able to understand how to implement such as [Bash - propagate value of variable to outside of the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390497/bash-propagate-value-of-variable-to-outside-of-the-loop).

I have Array which contains string and each string is use for making directories. Inside the loop everything is going fine but outside the loop the value is lost. i mean **echo $b** is not printing.  here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
#skipped portion of code
#......
#......
b=$(mkdir fff)
Array[0]="the"
Array[1]="world"

for i in "${!Array[@]}"
do
    echo $i
    b="$(mkdir  -p "$b/$v")"
done <<< "$b"
echo "$b"  // does not printing
```

Comment: What are you expecting `mkdir` to return? Why are you using `<<< "$b"` when nothing in the loop reads from standard input?

Comment: What do you think `$b` should print? `mkdir  -p` doesn't give any output.

Comment: You store output of mkdir command in b , but mkdir returns nothing

Comment: well you are right but i am luck it did nt effected mt whole code. then how can i copy whole path of created directory?

Comment: so topic changes how shell i save path in variable?

Comment: You already have path as `"$b/$v"`

Comment: but they are not storing in variable e.g c="$b/$v"...

Comment: oh  ok it starts working but it is not showing output like a/b/c. it is showing like a b c

Comment: `unset IFS; echo "$b/$v"`

Comment: can i write like this also unset IFS; c="$b/$v" ?