# How to keep a variable after a while loop bash

Tags: bash, shell, variables, while-loop, pipe

How do i keep a variable value after a while loop?

My intention here is to put a if clause within the while to count each time an operation has been done, but isn't working since the count resets after each while loop.

```
count=0

for file in $(ls /path)
do
   
   cat $ file | while read line
   do
      count=$((count+1))
      echo $count
   done

done

echo $count  #This echoes 0, even though the inner echo shows each sum.
```

Comment: The problem is the pipe, not the loop: [Propagate value of variable to outside of the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390497/propagate-value-of-variable-to-outside-of-the-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many methods.  In this case, it's probably easiest to drop the UUOC:

```
   while read line; do
      count=$((count+1))
      echo "$count"
   done < "$file"
```

which would be better written:

```
while read line; do echo "$((++count))"; done < "$file"
```

which would be even better written:

```
count=$(wc -l < "$file")
```

Although the last version sets count accurately (which the first two do not unless count is initialized) and does not emit the counts.

Comment: I have to say William, i would never imagine that the problem was cat all along. I changed the code here and it worked perfectly, many thanks!

Comment: The problem isn't really `cat`, the issue is the pipe.  The pipe runs in a subshell, and any variables defined or changed are only changed in the subshell.