# Check git status in pre-commit hook shell script

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell

I am writing a Git pre-commit hook client script and I want to filter through committed files and do something with the deleted ones.

I have found that with the following I can loop over all files included in a commit with the following.

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in $( exec git diff-index --cached --name-only HEAD )
  do
    echo $file
done
```

To find deleted files I believe I can use `git status --porcelain <file>` since it displays the first character as `D` when the file is deleted.

So what I need is help crafting the syntax to check whether the first character in the output of `git status --porcelain <file>` is a `D`.

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in $( exec git diff-index --cached --name-only HEAD )
  do
    # This line doesn't work but it's the best I've came up with.
    if git status --porcelain $lessFile == *"D"*; then
      echo "$file was deleted"
    fi
done
```

Or let me know if I'm way off base here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
 $( exec git status --porcelain | egrep "^D" | sed -e 's/^D  //' )
```

it may have problem for filename with space. or better

```
git diff-index --cached --name-status HEAD | awk '$1 == "D" { print $2 }' | while read file
do
   echo $file
done
```

see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412450/git-pre-commit-hook-changed-added-files).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Would you mind including the full context in your samples.  Not knowing much of anything about shell scripting I'm having difficulties putting the pieces together.

Comment: just use the 2nd one. it is full and complete

Comment: Awesome, I had copied it wrong the first time I tried it.  Thanks for your help.