# Automatic documentation verification with Aspell before Commit

Tags: git, github, aspell, smartgit

I am using GitHub repository for my project.The GUI I am utilizing is SmartGit and I would have a script that,before committing and pull it on the remote rep,verify with aspell if its orthograpically correct.By now I have to do every time

```
aspell --mode=tex --lang=it check Namefile.tex
```

Is there a way to automatize this?

Thank you

Comment: Put the aspell-call in a git pre-commit hook. It shall automatically run aspell on the changed *.tex files. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412450/git-pre-commit-hook-changed-added-files) and [this](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-git-commit-hooks-to-prevent-stupid-mistakes) for examples.