# git-hook only to run tests only if .py files change?

Tags: git, githooks

How can I make my git hook that only runs my unit tests when there are changes to .py files.

Comment: git has no idea how you want to classify the files it's tracking, if you want to do this the logic would have to be *in the hook*. If you want to know which files were modified in a pre-commit hook, for example, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2412450/3001761.

Comment: Question was badly worded, have edited.

Comment: Do you want to run your tests before commit, or before push?

Comment: Before push sounds like a good option since they take a while to run.

Comment: The first comment has information on how to code a script to get the changed files. Then you need to specialize that code to look only for your desired files. After that you need to use that script as your hook, keeping in mind that hooks SHOULD return exit(0) or exit(1) (0=sucess, 1=failure) to allow or abort the push in your case.